# AngularJS Authentication Service in a different file

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I am using this tutorial to create lazy loading:
http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

And this tutorial for authentication:
https://coderwall.com/p/f6brkg

I wanted to save the authentication service in a different file, say `AuthenticationService.js` and inject it as a dependency into my `app.js`. However, the app.js has to be bootstrapped, and returned before I can use the `define(['app'], function(){ ... }` for the service.

How can I accomplish this?

What I have so far:

**app.js**

```
define(
[
    'app/scripts/routes',
    'app/scripts/services/dependencyResolverFor',
    'app/scripts/services/AuthenticationService',
    'uiRouter'
], 
function(config, dependencyResolverFor, AuthenticationService) 
{
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.router']);
    console.log(AuthenticationService);
    // Register all providers. We can now lazy load files as needed.
    // Provide dependencies through the routes.js
    app.config([
        '$routeProvider',
        '$locationProvider',
        '$controllerProvider',
        '$compileProvider',
        '$filterProvider',
        '$provide',
        '$stateProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $stateProvider) {
            app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
            app.directive  = $compileProvider.directive;
            app.filter     = $filterProvider.register;
            app.factory    = $provide.factory;
            app.service    = $provide.service;

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

            if(config.routes !== undefined) {
                angular.forEach(config.routes, function(route, path) {
                   // Routing happens here
                });
            }
        }
    ]);

    // Check User
    app.run( ['$rootScope', '$state', function( $rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, currentRoute, prevRoute){ 
           // Authenticate here and have access to the service
        });
    }]);

    return app;
});
```

**AuthenticationService.js** (want it to be like this. Currently, it doesn't work because it says `app` is not defined, since it is not returned yet within app.js

```
define(['app'], function(app)
{
    app.service('AuthenticationService', function(){
        var isLogged = false;
        var user     = 'guest';
        var username = '';

        this.login = function() { isLogged = true; };
        this.checkLogin = function() { return isLogged; };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your AuthenticationService in a separate angular module, then make your main app depend on the sub-module (i.e. the module on which AuthenticationService is defined). something like...

```
angular.module('OtherModule', []).service('AuthenticationService', /* etc */);
```

then include the module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.router', 'OtherModule']);
```

edit: you can call .name on a module object (for example, the one getting injected into app.js) to get it's name, so you don't have to hard-code the 'OtherModule' string as a dependency, you can do something like

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.router', InjectedModule.name]);
```