# AngularJS sub-modules (and authentication)

Tags: angularjs, authentication, dependency-injection

Disclaimer: this is an ongoing "first project" in Angular so I'm still cutting my teeth.

Long story short, I'm using [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238490/user-login-system-with-mysql-database-with-angular-js) as a pattern for authentication (done via RESTful calls to a PHP script).  It works just fine.  The caveat comes in when I want it to work with an already existing controller on the Angular side of things.  Coming from my C++/Perl/Python background, I want to write it once and include it.  For that, I found [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794530/angularjs-authentication-service-in-a-different-file4).  It's not exactly working for me though.  For starters, my site was templated from another one, and the syntax is a bit different - something I've not quite figured out.  When I try InjectedModule.otherApp in myApp, I get errors.  The code looks something like this:

```
angular.module('otherApp', ['ngRoute','infinite-scroll'])
.controller("loginController",
            ['$scope',
            '$http',
            '$location',
            '$window',
            function($scope,$http,$location,$window) {
// Do a bunch of authentication stuff

}])

angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','infinite-scroll'])
.controller("imageController",
        ['$scope',
        '$http',
        '$location',
        '$window',
        function($scope,$http,$location,$window) {

// Guts of the page generated here

}])
```

Ideally I'd like the imageController to depend on the authentication controller, and of course have control over what's displayed based on authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers should not be depended upon. You should use services for that.
First, you should build an authentication service.

```
angular.module('authentication')
.service('authService', function(){
    var isAuthenticated = false;
    var user     = 'guest';
    var username = '';

    return {
      login: function() { isAuthenticated = true; },
      isAuthenticated: function() { return isAuthenticated; },
      loggedInUser: function() { return user; }
    }
});
```

Now, your controllers can invoke authentication logic from this service:

```
angular.module('authentication', ['ngRoute','infinite-scroll'])
.controller("loginController",
        ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', 'authService',
        function($scope,$http,$location,$window, authService) {

  // Do a bunch of authentication stuff
  $scope.login = function LoginUser() {
    authService.login();
  }

}]);

// include 'authentication' module - 'images' module will depend on it
angular.module('images', ['ngRoute','infinite-scroll', 'authentication'])
.controller("imageController",
    ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', 'authService',
    function($scope,$http,$location,$window, authService) {

  // Guts of the page generated here
  $scope.loadImages = function LoadImages() {
    if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      // do authenticated user image load logic
    } else {
      // do unauthenticated user image load logic
    }
  }
}]);
```

Your app should also include both modules:

```
angular.module('bootstraper', [
  'authentication',
  'images'
])
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'm at work now but I will tinker with this when I get home.

Comment: Finally getting around to this.  Could there be a syntax error in the service part?  I'm getting an error on the first block of code.  Feel free to have a look here: http://www.gamengai.com/authtest.html

I didn't have a chance to mess around much further than that.

Comment: you need to initialize the module when you create a first service/controller in it...

you will need to change the order of your controllers/services, first add the controller as it defines the module, `angular.module('authentication', ['ngRoute','infinite-scroll']).controller`, then also define a service on it...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Vinko.  Any chance I can get a Fiddle, or similar?  I think I'm messing something up (and was halfway going through a tutorial when I stumbled on this but am still getting errors.)  Also not totally use to Angular's console output.

Comment: Thanks -- heading to the gym but will get on this.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what's going on, and is enough for me to get going.  I'll need to read up on a few other things.  Still learning a lot about the Angular framework.   Quite a bit different from C++ & Python which I do at work, but cool nonetheless.  You've been a huge help.